# Flutter: Merge two images and store it in local storage as a single image

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to merge two images and store them as a single image in local storage in Flutter

Comment: If you want to overlap them, use the Stack widget. Maybe give transparency to a png image if you can

Comment: how do you want to merge them? one image next to one? both images overlaps with some transparency gradient? anything else?

Comment: I want to merge them next to one don't want to overlap. You can think of it as two pages in the book left page and right page, I want to  show them as a single rectangular  sheet

Comment: so maybe use `Row`?

Comment: Thought of it. But while tap has to show the zoomed view as a single image. Like in gallery apps

Comment: zoomed? then use `Transform` > `Row`?

Comment: could you elaborate

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html

Comment: I also want to store it  as a single image

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found the answer, Thanks to this awesome library https://pub.dev/packages/image

```
final image1 = decodeImage(File('imageA.jpg').readAsBytesSync());
final image2 = decodeImage(File('imageB.jpg').readAsBytesSync());
final mergedImage = Image(image1.width + image2.width, max(image1.height, image2.height));
copyInto(mergedImage, image1, blend = false);
copyInto(mergedImage, image2, dstx = image1.width, blend = false);

final documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final file = new File(join(documentDirectory.path, "merged_image.jpg"));
file.writeAsBytesSync(encodeJpg(mergedImage));
```

Comment: Hello, How to join multiple dynamic images ?

Comment: how can we convert a png image into jpg? Please share. Thanks.

Comment: @Jagath Ratchagan  Can you find the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64604475/is-there-a-way-to-merge-dynamically-loaded-image-file-to-one-image-file-in-flutt   I had a piece of code of yours

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Jagath

Comment: What is join 
final file = new File(join(documentDirectory.path, "merged_image.jpg"));
in this line

Comment: incase someone else stumbles upon this issue the copyInto function has been renamed to compositeImage

Comment: copyInto is deprecated now, what is the solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try giving this package a shot and save the resulting Image as usual
https://pub.dev/packages/merge_images

Answer (score 0):

By using: merge_images: ^2.0.0-nullsafety

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:merge_images/merge_images.dart';

Future<void> _mergeImages() async {
final imageList = await _createImageList([_frontImage, _backImage]);
ui.Image image = await ImagesMergeHelper.margeImages(imageList,
fit: true, direction: Axis.vertical, backgroundColor: Colors.white);
}
```